# Android listview change layout size of subviews

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am building a bar chart that is to be used in a listview. The bars are built with a LinearLayout and Weights. A simple representation of the bar chart containing only one bar provided in XML below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/counter_weight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/visible_part_of_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want this bar to represent say 60 percent, you set the weight of visible_part_of_bar to 60 and the weight of counter_weight to 40.

The view in itself is working just fine on its own but inside a listview, the height of the subviews aren't updated correctly. A really odd thing to add to this is that you can update the background color of the bar in the listview, but everything else seems to be ignored.

Any thoughts of what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to leverage the LinearLayout weighting system, but it doesn't look like you have things set up properly.

- Add the following to the LinearLayout xml tag:
  android:weightSum="1.0"
- Add the following to the first view (for 60%
  height): android:layout_weight=".6"
- Add the following to the second
  view (for 60% height): android:layout_weight=".4"

If you are applying these layout changes programmatically, you will probably want to call requestLayout() on the root view for the row after making changes.

Comment: The weight sum of a LinearLayout doesn't need to sum up to 1.0. As previously mentioned the view works just fine outside a ListView.

I tried calling requestLayout on the rootview, unfortunately it had no effect. Thanks for trying!